# Upgrading to Bluetooth 4.0 internally iMac 2011 21.5 (A1311)

Tags: imac, bluetooth, upgrade

Has anyone successfully upgraded the OEM internal Bluetooth2.0 to Bluetooth 4.0?

I want to do the upgrade to enable AirDrop with my iPad Pro and iPhone X.

This site [OSXWIFI](https://www.osxwifi.com/product/imac-2009-imac-2010-and-imac-2011-apple-broadcom-bcm94360cd-802-11-a-b-g-n-ac-with-bluetooth-4-0/) claims it can be done without any soldering or cutting of cables...simply plug'n'play.  It does seem a little pricey though.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Plug in an external USB adapter. Much easier and less expensive, even if you’re already in the Mac to repair things.

I have no reason to doubt that part would work since the OS and software all support this and it’s about the hardware receiver that needs swapping whether you do it internally or externally. This works.

Comment: Yes I know I could do that, but I really want it done internally, less clutter

Comment: @JonathanS. do it.